# Mirth Connect HTTP Listener

Tags: mirth

I am new to Mirth Connect but was wondering could it be used to pull down vaccine information sheets from the CDC.gov website. They provide the XML source code on the CDC website and I was hoping that as new updated vaccine sheets were added it would download them to a folder on our server. Is this something you would us the http listener for? Sorry if it is a little vague just trying to get an idea right now before diving in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but not feasible. First of all, it's not HTTP Listener (Source connector) that you need, it's HTTP Sender (Destination connector) that retrieves the required file (PDF if I'm correct) from the CDC site.

Then you need to configure your Source connector as JavaScript Reader to periodically trigger your HTTP Sender destination.

All of these can be easily implemented as a single Java/.NET utility without installing Mirth Connect as an engine.